# Yii node socket is not working when i set up in my actual server

Tags: php, node.js, yii, yii-extensions

I am using the yii-node-socket plugin successfully in my local computer. However I am not able to run it successfully in my server and I saw the following error in my log:

> connect deprecated utils.merge: use utils-merge npm moduleinstead at 
>   extensions/yii-node-socket/lib/js/server/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:36:9
>   info: socket.io start

```
https://github.com/oncesk/yii-node-socket
```

The following was my previous post regarding this plugin which I have successfully configured:

[Click here on the previous post which i did to my localhost setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250328/yii-node-socket-is-not-working-for-me)

In my main.php i changed the following setting:

```
'nodeSocket' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.yii-node-socket.lib.php.NodeSocket',
            'host' => 'dev.helloworld.com',  // default is 127.0.0.1, can be ip or domain name, without http
            'port' => 3001,      // default is 3001, should be integer
            'allowedServerAddresses'=>array('XXX.XXX.177.20','127.0.0.1')
        )
```

XXX.XXX is denoted with my server IP address. www.helloworld.com is the domain but i am using the subdomain dev.helloworld.com

My node version is v0.10.25 and my npm version is v0.10.25. It is exactly the same setting as my localhost server.

I am unable to broadcast any messages to clients. I did the same setting as what I did in my previous post and it worked but not for my server. Please help

Comment: Just a thought: I dont use this extension because it is totally crap. Go back to native node.js and you will be fine.

Comment: For a beginning stage, there is a need to use the extension. Of coz in the future, the direction is to just use node.js. I have solved it by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that curl was not installed.